# Convert a dynamically generated string to raw text

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and i struck an issue wherein, I am dynamically retrieving a string from a dictionary which looks like this

`files="eputilities/epbalancing_alb/referenced assemblies/model/cv6_xmltypemodel_xp2.cs"`

I am unable to to perform any actions on this particular file as it is reading the path as 2 different strings

`eputilities/epbalancing_alb/referenced and  assemblies/model/cv6_xmltypemodel_xp2.cs`

as there is a space between referenced and assemblies.

I wanted to know how to convert this to raw_string (ignore the space, but still keep the space between the two and consider it as one string)

I'm not able to figure this out although several comments where there on the web.

Please do help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to pass the string to an external program? Python has no problems with spaces in file names

Comment: can you show the dictionary..

Comment: @gnibbler: Yes I am passing this string variable to an external program like a source code manager which checks out the file from it.

Comment: @user2002985, ok. That's the part you are doing wrong. Post the code that you're using to call the external program and we'll tell you how to fix it.

Comment: ccm co is the command to check out a file in a source code manager
dict_ir_task[key1] = a dynamically retrieved variable passed as an arguement
path_ergoplan = a dynamically retrieved path say "D:\PE5R23SP1\ergoplan-PE5R23SP1\ergoplan"

files = is the dynamically retrieved file path which I am having an issue with say "/eputilities/epbalancing_alb/referenced assemblies/model/cv6_xmltypemodel_xp2.cs" 



ret_co=os.system("ccm co -task " + dict_ir_task[key1] + " " + path_ergoplan + "/" + files + " >>co.log")

Comment: Any ideas towards the solution guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments to the other answer, I understand that you want to execute some external tool and pass a parameter (a filename) to it. This parameter, however, has spaces in it.

I'd propose to approaches; definitely, I'd use `subprocess`, not `os.system`.

```
import subprocess

# Option 1
subprocess.call([path_to_executable, parameter])

# Option 2
subprocess.call("%s \"%s\"" % (path_to_executable, parameter), shell=True)
```

For me, both worked, please check if they work yor you as well.

Explanations:

Option 1 takes a list of strings, where the first string has to be the path to the executable and all others are interpreted as command line arguments. As `subprocess.call knows about each of these entities, it properly calls the external so that it understand that`parameter` is to be interpreted as one string with spaces - and not as two or more parameters.

Option 2 is different. With the keyword-argument `shell=True` we tell `subprocess.call` to execute the call through a shell, i.e., the first positional argument is "interpreted as if it was typed like this in a shell". But now, we have to prepare this string accordingly. So what would you do if you had to type a filename with spaces as a parameter? You'd put it between double quotes. This is what I do here.

Comment: This works perfectly fine.

Thanks a lot.

I used the command 

subprocess.call(["ccm", "co", "-task", dict_ir_task[key1], path_ergoplan + "/" + files, ">>co.log"])

Answer (score 1):

Standard string building in python works like this

```
'%s foo %s'%(str_val_1, str_val_2)
```

So if I'm understanding you right either have a list of two strings or two different string variables.

For the prior do this:

```
' '.join(list)
```

For the latter do this:

```
'%s %s'%(string_1, string_2)
```

Comment: I have a single string e.g D:\pat\reg prg\text.1
when I am reading this string I am getting the string only upto D:\pat\reg  whereas I would like to read the entire path

Comment: what happens when you print that variable?

Comment: The variable prints fine, exactly how i want it with the complete path, but when this variable is passed to os.system(execute a command in a source code management tool) as an arguement  i get the issue of the path splitting into 2 with the space as the delimiter

Comment: Where is your python file in relationship to that directory?

Comment: You can do this a couple of different ways, if you have it in a relatively nearby location you can build it dynamically based on your current folder context. What's probably going to be the easiest for you in this context though is to do something like:

    import os
    file_path = os.path.join('D:\', 'pat', 'reg prg', 'text.1')

Comment: No, the location of my python file does not relate to the directory retrieved

Comment: Better yet - do os.path.normpath(your_string)

Comment: See the thing is I am dynamically retrieving the path from a list which is part of a dictionary. And the path is on the same machine but in a different drive as compared to the python source code.

Comment: I tried the os.path.normpath(str), but unfortunately that does not work.

Comment: I don't see a problem with python able to read spaces in my path as stated by  gnibbler. So the problem is trying to execute the external command by passing this variable using the os.system() cmd in python

Comment: Oh. Put "s around it... so '"D:\your path"'.  It has to do with the fact that you're running a command line argument and in windows cmd for paths that have spaces you have to have it in quotes.

Comment: how would can i do that????? I have to put "s around a variable as the variable stores the dynamically retrieved path.

Comment: Is it possible that i could convert it to a UTF-8 encoding mode?

will that work?